# Why does my keyboard type multiple letters when I type on the built-in keyboard or an external keyboard?

Tags: linux

I have a Dell Vostro 5470 running Linux Deepin 20.6 and when I type the keys repeat.

When I type this in:

```
sudo dmidecode | grep keyboard
```

I get this:

```
 8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
```

This is the unique think I know about my keyboard, but I guess is not a specific notebook keyboard problem because when I plug in a external keyboard the problem still happens.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: (1) What is your desktop environment? (2) Does the problem occur in a pure tty? (Ctrl+Alt+F2 or so).

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're using the latest BIOS version. Some Dell laptops were affected by a similar issue in the past and it was fixed by a BIOS update.

The most convenient way to update BIOS is to enter your service tag on the [Dell Support website](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us). The service tag is a 7 character sequence that can be found on the bottom of a laptop. That will give you access to all available updates. Look for a BIOS update and install it.

Alternatively install Dell Update or Dell Command Update (depends on laptop model; can be found the same way as explained above) and let it find and install updates.

On Linux you could use `fwupdmgr`. Some distributions come with built-in firmware update feature (eg. Pop!_OS, in the Settings app). Make sure that capsule updates are enabled in BIOS.